# Like rleid but ignoring NAs

Tags: r

I have a vector that contains numeric values and NAs. I want another vector of the same length, consisting of Id's that count up each time a new number occurs in the original.

```
#What I have
have<-c(1.1, NA, 1.1, NA, NA, 1.1, NA, 
     1.5, NA, 2, NA, 1.5, 
     NA, 1.1, NA, NA, 1.5, NA)

#What I want
want<-c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8)

#Both what I have and want side by side
cbind(want,have)
```

What I've tried

```
#This is pretty far off, it both treats NA's as not duplicated and treats 
cbind(have,cumsum(!duplicated(have)))

#This is almost there, but NAs get counted as new groups
cbind(have,rleid(have))

#Can't fill down because some are duplicated between NA's
cbind(rleid(fill(as.data.frame(have),have)$have),have)
```

This must be a duplicate question but I can't find the right thing.

Comment: `with(rle(have), rep(cumsum(!is.na(values)), lengths))` should work

Comment: Even a bit simpler: `cumsum(!is.na(have))` at least for your example and desired output.

Comment: Either of these is an acceptable answer if someone wants to post it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about replacing `NA`s with 0 taking `cumsum` converting to `factor` and then to `integer`

```
as.integer(factor(cumsum(replace(have, is.na(have), 0))))
#[1] 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 6 6 7 7 7 8 8
```

Although it works for the data given here but this is not full proof method and it will fail if you have actual 0's in your data.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is searching for a `tidyverse` solution, here is an easy to read and understand one:

```r
library(dplyr)  
  
have <- c(1.1, NA, 1.1, NA, NA, 1.1, NA, 
          1.5, NA, 2, NA, 1.5, 
          NA, 1.1, NA, NA, 1.5, NA)

have_df <- tibble(have)

have_df %>%
  mutate(
    newGameState_seg = cumsum(
      (!is.na(have)) & (have != lag(ifelse(is.na(have), -999, have), default = -999))
    )
  )
#> # A tibble: 18 x 2
#>     have newGameState_seg
#>    <dbl>            <int>
#>  1   1.1                1
#>  2  NA                  1
#>  3   1.1                2
#>  4  NA                  2
#>  5  NA                  2
#>  6   1.1                3
#>  7  NA                  3
#>  8   1.5                4
#>  9  NA                  4
#> 10   2                  5
#> 11  NA                  5
#> 12   1.5                6
#> 13  NA                  6
#> 14   1.1                7
#> 15  NA                  7
#> 16  NA                  7
#> 17   1.5                8
#> 18  NA                  8
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>