# Something similar to rleid that uses NAs to restart the counter in R?

Tags: r

This is somewhat similar to [Like rleid but ignoring NAs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57616774/like-rleid-but-ignoring-nas), but I want NAs "ignored" in the counter (i.e., if we have NA, use NA in the counter). I need to initialize a counter that starts at 1 to count the occurrence of a number, keeps the previous counter if I have the same number as above, and restarts counter at 1 after any NA occurrence.

I have this:

```
# have
months <- c(1, 8, 1, 1, 1, NA, NA, 2, 6, NA)

# want
months_counter <- c(1, 2, 3, 3, 3, NA, NA, 1, 2, NA)
```

I have tried different ways using `rleid` but all of them seem to not have the functionality of ignoring NAs as above. Something to be applied in a `data.table` would be even more appreciated!

Comment: This doesn't seem anything like "ignoring" NAs, it seems like you want NAs to reset the group counter. You want them to add additional meaning to NAs.

Comment: @GregorThomas right! I want NAs to be a placeholder for resetting the counter, but not counted. I'll modify for clarification!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can add a column counting `NA`s to use as a grouping column for `rleid` but only set the values on rows where `months` is not `NA`:

```
library(data.table)
dt = data.table(months = c(1, 8, 1, 1, 1, NA, NA, 2, 6, NA))

dt[, grouper := cumsum(is.na(months))][
  !is.na(months),
  result := rleid(months),
  by = grouper
]
dt
#    months grouper result
#  1:      1       0      1
#  2:      8       0      2
#  3:      1       0      3
#  4:      1       0      3
#  5:      1       0      3
#  6:     NA       1     NA
#  7:     NA       2     NA
#  8:      2       2      1
#  9:      6       2      2
# 10:     NA       3     NA
```